# How generate nodejs express dependencies package.json

Tags: node.js, dependencies, express

As I started to develop my first nodejs express application, I added many packages with npm.

I would like to know if there is a way to generate a `package.json` file containing all the current dependencies or the list of the current packages under the `nodes_modules` directory.

Comment: Once you get this resolved, I'd recommend using `npm install --save` and `npm install --save-dev` when adding new packages. Those commands both install the package and update your `package.json` which is an awesome way to not screw things up. It's also worth mentioning that you can run `npm init` when starting a new project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run `npm list` to see what you have installed. Run `npm shrinkwrap` to build a `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file, which you can use as a starting reference to build a proper `package.json`. My workflow is always to update package.json and then run `npm install`. I never run `npm install foo` to get some package because it creates risk of forgetting to add it to `package.json` and then having your application fail to start on deployment.

**Updated to add**: These days I *do* run `npm install --save foo` or `npm install --save-dev foo` since I have now decided the `~0.4.3` version numbers it adds to `package.json` are better than my former preference for `0.4.x` since the `~` gives you a more precise minimum version number.

Comment: You don't use `npm install --save foo`?

Comment: Nah, I don't like the ~ versions it specifies, but I'm really picky about my package.json. npm install --save is fine for general use I think.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way to generate it after you have all you package installed ... i'll be more careful the next time !!

Answer (score 10):

Just run `npm init` in the same directory as your project.

You'll be asked a list of questions (name, version, description, etc.) and once complete, it will generate a `package.json` file with all of the dependencies as currently installed in the `node_modules` directory.

Comment: this works as long as you don't already have a package.json file existing in the directory

Comment: rename package.json to package.json.old and run npm init. After that you can take out dependancies of the newly generated package.json and put them in to old. When that is done delete newly generated package.json and rename package.json.old to package.json.